# How to know precisely when a SWIFT is issued by a bank?

Tags: international-transfer, wire-transfer

According to what I understand from SWIFT principles, the issuance time and date for a SWIFT instruction are held in the "Message Input Reference" (Also known as MIR in the SWIFT terminology), like here:

```
---------------------  Instance Type and Transmission --------------    
   Notification (Transmission) of Original sent to SWIFT (ACK)
   Network Delivery Status   : Network Ack
   Priority/Delivery         : Normal
   Message Input Reference   : 1624 170321________XXX_______461  
--------------------------- Message Header -------------------------         
   Swift Input                   : FIN 103 Single Customer Credt Transfer
   Sender   : ________XXX
```

Where 1624 is the time of issuance (16:24) and 170321 is the date of issuance (21st of March 2017).

Can someone confirm my assessment?

Answer (score 1):

I think technically the MIR includes the date of issuance but not the time, see the references [here](https://www2.swift.com/uhbonline/books/public/en_uk/udic/index.htm?subpage=b16.htm). What you have there looks like a timestamp followed by the MIR.

If you look at [this example from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBTEG_4.3.0/com.ibm.wbia_adapters.doc/doc/swift/swift72.htm) they also show the input time as a separate field.